# Connect Android device to Android studio in Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, android, 18.04, android-studio

My lsusb displays

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2717:ff48  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I guess device 005 is my phone.
I get to transfer files using usb.
Android studio still can't detect my phone.
I have no idea what to place on `51-android.rules` as my device is Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 pro.

Comment: you can try using `adb`

Comment: @damadam I think more specifically if you run `adb devices` you should see the connected device

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2717:ff48` is not your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think editing `51-android.rules` file is important. Before connecting your device into Android Studio you need to enable **USB Debugging**. And if you're a Redmi user, you need to enable an extra setting called **Install via USB** in Developer Options. (I am a Redmi user too :))

To enable USB debugging goto **Settings** - **About Phone** - and tap 7 times continuously on **MIUI version**. Now you get a message "You're now developer". If you've already enabled it, you'll get "No need you already developer".

After that goto **Settings** - **Additional Settings** - **Developer Options** - and enable **USB debugging** also **Install via USB**

But, you may face a weird problem like "The device is temporarily restricted" while enabling Install via USB. To resolve this problem please check this StackOverflow thread: [Install app via usb: The device is temporarily restricted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46020237/5180017)

Now you're good to connect your device with Android Studio.